# Is there a Visual Basic Interactive Window in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is this possible to have a Visual Basic Interactive window in Visual Studio 2015 like we have for C#?

[image]

Comment: The list of pending issues can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen%20label%3AInteractive-ScriptingLogic%20label%3ALanguage-VB). It doesn't seem to be very high on anyone's priority list (most of the issues involved haven't been updated for two-three years), so if you want to help move this forward by contributing, it would be welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the time of writing the original answer to this, VB.net interactive was in the pipeline, but no longer. As this answer had been accepted, I can't delete it, so here it stays :-/

Comment: For those who came here from Google, no, there isn't a VB Interactive window in VS 2019 at the time I'm writing this, nor do they plan to implement it.

Comment: @fdrobidoux Thanks - I'd forgotten I'd posted this, If you want to repost your comment as an answer, I'll delete mine as it's no longer accurate :)

Comment: Eh, no worries, move on.

Answer (score 1):

For those who came here from Google, no, there isn't a VB Interactive window in VS 2019 at the time I'm writing this, nor do they plan to implement it.

Answer (score -1):

If you clone the Roslyn repository from GitHub (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) one of the projects is called vbi, and you can produce a non-GUI version of C# Interactive (no Intellisense obviously) that does a lot of what C# Interactive does.

From a brief investigation it seems to need each line expressed as a function/method call, e.g., evaluating 3 + 4 gives you an error, but System.Console.WriteLine(3 + 4) displays 7 (you also seem to have to full qualify methods). However you can evaluation System.Math.Pow(2, 7) and get 128 as the answer.

Since it's VB input is case insensitive so system.console.writeline(3 + 4) works.